# Lights And Shadow Animation, lowering the opacity of a shadow

Tags: animation, light, shadows

I'm doing an animation using EEVEE render,I set up 2 lights to my scene. Once the animation is exported, the drop shadow doesn't seem to intense. The reflections I like, giving it a realistic glare as the Handle animates. But the shadow doesn't seem to be there. How can I improve the scene set up, or what do I need to do to get a better shadow?

Thank you.

https://streamable.com/3ime3w

[image]

Comment: Try selecting your light, and in the light properties section (the tab with the lightbulb), under shadows, check the box that says "contact shadows".

Comment: That did the trick, how ever, Im trying to fade the opacity of the shadow because it's too intense. I tried manipulating the values but that wont work. the only way I could fade the opacity was by lowering the strength. Any information how to lower the opacity of the shadow not to be so intense? Thank you.

https://ibb.co/LSh0snS